# Print ASCII-characters

Tags: r, ascii

I would like to create ASCII characters in loop based on an integer variable.
The result should be like this, but without the character vector:

```
 v<-c("A","B","C","D","E")

 for (i in 1:5) print(paste("ASCII:",v[i]))
```

If I start with

```
 for (i in 65:69)
```

how do I continue?

Thanks&kind regards

Comment: You can use `seq_along`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`intToUtf8()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/utf8Conversion.html):

```
for (i in 65:69) print(paste('ASCII:',intToUtf8(i)));
## [1] "ASCII: A"
## [1] "ASCII: B"
## [1] "ASCII: C"
## [1] "ASCII: D"
## [1] "ASCII: E"
```

---

This is not directly relevant to your question, but we can utilize the `multiple` argument of `intToUtf8()` to generate a character vector of the output in one line:

```
paste('ASCII:',intToUtf8(65:69,T));
## [1] "ASCII: A" "ASCII: B" "ASCII: C" "ASCII: D" "ASCII: E"
```